# memory mapped files

Tags: c, unix, mmap, memory-mapped-files

I wrote a code for writing the content to the mapped buffer which mapped by using the mmap() system call.
After I did some the changes in the mapped buffer,then I called the msync().It should update to the file on disk.

But,It doesn't made any changes to the file on disk.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#define FILEMODE S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH
#define MAX 150

main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
int fd,ret,len;
long int len_file;
struct stat st;
char *addr;
char buf[MAX];


if(argc > 1)
{
    if((fd = open(argv[1],O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT ,FILEMODE)) < 0)
        perror("Error in file opening");

    if((ret=fstat(fd,&st)) < 0)
        perror("Error in fstat");

    len_file = st.st_size;

           /*len_file having the total length of the file(fd).*/


    if((addr=mmap(NULL,len_file,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE,fd,0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        perror("Error in mmap");

    len = len_file; 

    while((fgets(buf,MAX,stdin)) != NULL)
    {
        strcat(addr+len,buf);
        printf( "Val:%s\n",addr ) ; //Checking purpose
        len = len + (strlen(buf));
    }
    if((msync(addr,len,MS_SYNC)) < 0)
        perror("Error in msync");

    if( munmap(addr,len) == -1)
        printf("Error:\n");
    printf("addr %p\n",addr);
}
else
{
    printf("Usage a.out <filename>\n");
}
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want your changes to be reflected in the on-disk file, you must map the file as `MAP_SHARED`, not `MAP_PRIVATE`.

Additionally, you cannot extend the file simply by writing beyond the end of the mapping.  You must use `ftruncate()` to extend the file to the new size, then change the mapping to include the new portion of the file.  The portable way to change the mapping is to unmap the mapping then recreate it with the new size; on Linux you can instead use `mremap()`.

Your `len` and `len_file` variables should be of type `size_t`, and you should use `memcpy()` rather than `strcat()`, since you know exactly the length of the string, exactly where you want to copy it, and you *don't* want to copy the null-terminator.

The following modification of your code works on Linux (using `mremap()`) :

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#define FILEMODE S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH
#define MAX 150

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int fd, ret;
    size_t len_file, len;
    struct stat st;
    char *addr;
    char buf[MAX];

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage a.out <filename>\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((fd = open(argv[1],O_RDWR | O_CREAT, FILEMODE)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error in file opening");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((ret = fstat(fd,&st)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error in fstat");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    len_file = st.st_size;

    /*len_file having the total length of the file(fd).*/

    if ((addr = mmap(NULL,len_file,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0)) == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("Error in mmap");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((fgets(buf,MAX,stdin)) != NULL)
    {
        len = len_file;
        len_file += strlen(buf);
        if (ftruncate(fd, len_file) != 0)
        {
            perror("Error extending file");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if ((addr = mremap(addr, len, len_file, MREMAP_MAYMOVE)) == MAP_FAILED)
        {
            perror("Error extending mapping");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        memcpy(addr+len, buf, len_file - len);
        printf( "Val:%s\n",addr ) ; //Checking purpose
    }
    if((msync(addr,len,MS_SYNC)) < 0)
        perror("Error in msync");

    if (munmap(addr,len) == -1)
        perror("Error in munmap");

    if (close(fd))
        perror("Error in close");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this missing a call to close(fd) ?

Comment: @Ryan: Yes - I had just made the minimal changes to the code in the question, but you're right - `close()` should be called so that we can check for an error return.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you've provided a mapping for the file that is exactly the size of the file. If you create the file in your call to `open(2)`, it will have a length of `0`, and I wouldn't be surprised if the kernel doesn't bother setting up any kind of memory mapping from a `0` length mapping. (Maybe it does? I've never tried...)

I would suggest using `ftruncate(2)` to extend the length of your file *before* performing the mapping. (Note that extending files using `ftruncate(2)` isn't very portable; not all platforms provide extending functionality and not all filesystem drivers support the extending functionality. See your system's manpage for details.)

You must use the `MAP_SHARED` mapping for your file modifications to be saved to disk.

Your use of `perror(3)` isn't quite correct; `perror(3)` will *not* terminate your program, so it will continue executing with incorrect assumptions:

```
if((ret=fstat(fd,&st)) < 0)
    perror("Error in fstat");
```

Should read:

```
if((ret=fstat(fd,&st)) < 0) {
    perror("Error in fstat");
    exit(1);
}
```

(Or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` if you want to be more portable -- I find that a little harder on the eyes but I live in Linux-land.)

`strcat(3)` expects to find an ASCII NUL character (byte value `0x00`, C representation `'\0'`) -- the usual C end-of-string marker -- at the end of the `dest` string. Your file will not contain an ASCII NUL if you create it in this program -- its length is zero, after all -- and I don't know the consequences of trying to read a zero-byte file via `mmap(2)`. If the file already exists and has data in it, it *probably* doesn't have an ASCII NUL encoded in the file. `strcat(3)` is almost certainly the wrong tool to write into your file. (No one wants ASCII NULs in their files anyway.) Try `memcpy(3)` instead.

Comment: From an anonymous reviewer: _The original author confused "file is append-only" with "fd is opened in append mode". A file becomes append-only e.g. running `chattr +a THEFILE` in a shell. `O_APPEND` dictates the behavior of the write system call, but not memory mappings._ -- edited to remove the `MAP_SHARED` bit as a result. :)